# How to manage database and queries of a multi-tagged/multi-categorized article/post

Tags: php, mysql

I have a article website and each article has some tags. How should be my database structure?

This is my article table (*article*):

```
article_id (key)  |  article_content  |  article_title  |  article_lang_id
```

This is the list of my tags *(tag_list):*

```
tag_list_id (key)  |  tag_list_name  |  tag_list_description
```

And this is my tag table *(tag_link)*:

```
  tag_id (key)   |   article_id (f-key)  |   tag_list_id (f-key)
```

I echo the article content with php, how can I echo (I mean showing tag bellow content) tags bellow the content?

This is my question:

**1- How can I show each content tags near content?**

(each content can has less than 5 tags)

**2-What is the MYSQL query that I can run to select my tags with content?**
(is there any professional MySQL orders to select content with tags form tag_link and then select the name of tag from tag_list and then show it near article, can I do it with MySQL orders like join, having, on and several other? How?)

**3-Is my database structure for tagging true?**

(I can do this with php variables and ... , but I need to do it by MySQL)

Comment: what are you been trying so far? show us the queries

Comment: @avisheks I do it with PHP, but this is not standard and true, because of security and speed reasons

Comment: which ever language you'r been using you must have tries some queries. btw how you mean "each content tags near content"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have :

```
a table for Articles(tablename=> articles)
a table for Tags(tablename=> tags)
a table for Tags which are assigned to articles (tablename=> tags_articles)
// note the naming of the third table which shows its a relation between the first table and // the second
```

When a user clicks on an article link to view it, something like this should generally happen:

The content of the article (title, description, images etc.) are fetched from DB and echoed.

based on the id of the article, the related ids of the tags from tags_article are fetched, and the each information of the tag(usually only id and title) is fetched from tags table.

You can get it from one query known as JOINT in SQL:

You select fields of article, and then relate it to tags_articles table, and eventually retrieves the list of tags associated with that product through their IDs. Literally, something like this happens:

> select an article from articles table whose id is $id.
>
> Then, please select tag_id and article_id for me from tags_articles
>   table whose article_id is $id;
>
> In the end, I want you to select all tags information(probably only id
>   and title) from tags table whose id is equal to tags_articles.tag_id

The SQL query:

```
SELECT articles.id, articles.title, articles.description, articles.image, tags.id, tags.title FROM articles INNER JOIN tags_articles ON articles.id=tags_articles.article_id INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id=tags_articles.tag_id WHERE articles.id=$id
```

**EDIT**

If you have an article with id 1 and title "Computer Software History", and it has two tags of "history" and "software" then it happens to be:

In articles table:

```
   id : 1
   title: Computer Software History
   image: path/to/image
   description : A long long description
```

In tags table there are many tags:

```
   id: 1, title: Computer
   id: 2, title: History
   id: 3, title: Youtube
   id: 4, title: Web
   id: 5, title: Software
   id: 6, title: Hardware
   // and hundredth of other tags
```

and in tags_articles table you have again many tags assigned to many articles...but we focus on the rows which are related to your article with id 1:

```
   // many rows before
   article_id : 1, tag_id : 2 // look in the tags_table for this id
   article_id : 1, tag_id : 5 // look in the tags_table for this id
   // many rows after
```

With the query above, you take out the relation of these tables and extract the data and use it.

Comment: باید دوباره تشکر کنم، خیلی ممنون، فقط میشه یک کم توضیح بدید چطور می توانم به صورت حرفه ای مای اس کیو ال را یاد بگیرم؟

Comment: KGL don't speak farsi in here, otherwise you will get banned by moderators, delete all your comments and I will explain you how.

Comment: I know that, this is my real account that banned because of spamming :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/3176270/kermani

Comment: I have added to the answer, see the bottom of the answer for the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

This will list-down all the tags related as comma separated value to an article:
You can filter down by particular article_id if you want.

```
SELECT 
article_contents article,group_concat(tag_list_name) tags
FROM
article a
INNER JOIN tag_link m article_id=a.id
INNER JOIN tag_list t tag_list_id=t.id
WHERE article_id="??"
```

You database structure seems correct to me. "article" and "tags" tables has many to many relationship between themselves, you would need another tables for mapping. You have it.